# Executing terminal command from java program

Tags: java, android, file, terminal, command

I'm writing a program in java that makes monkey test on an android virtual device. In this program I run the following three commands.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process clear = rt.exec("/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb logcat -c");
Process monkey = rt.exec("/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell monkey -p gy.softwaretesting1 --throttle 200 200");
Process report = rt.exec("/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb logcat -d *:E | grep AndroidRuntime >> /Users/<username>/Documents/workspace/SoftwareTesting/fileReport.txt");
```

The first one clears logcat buffer, second one starts monkey test and third one takes crush report and prints it to a file. The first two do exactly I want, the third one, however, doesn't. When I take the part for creating file in third command to another command it stops working too. I guess there is a problem about creating file via terminal command from java program. If you have any ideas please help.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to security. Java may has not the permission to use this folder and does not have read write permissions there.If this is the problem you should grant the permissions to it

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.gmail.jackkobec.java.core;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * @Author Jack <jackkobec>
 */
public class ExecuteTerminalCommandsFromJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Gets runtime
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        // Declare a command with parameters as string array
        String[] commandWithParameters = {"free", "-h"};
        // Execute command and get it process  
        Process commandExecuteProcess = runtime.exec(commandWithParameters);

        // Gets input stream from process, convert it to buffered reader
        BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(commandExecuteProcess.getInputStream()));
        // Read line by line from process input stream decorated as buffered reader
        lineReader.lines().forEach(System.out::println);

        // Gets errors input stream from process, convert it to buffered reader
        BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(commandExecuteProcess.getErrorStream()));
        // Read line by line from process errors input stream decorated as buffered reader
        errorReader.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

> Output is like:
>                total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available Mem:            15G        4,8G        7,9G        561M
>   2,7G        9,7G Swap:          7,6G          0B        7,6G